# Get matlab struct as a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, struct

Im trying to load a .mat file in python using:

```
Y = scipy.io.loadmat('XYZ.mat')
```

These are the keys of the dictionary created

```
dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'X', 'Y'])
```

`type(Y['X'])` is

```
<class 'scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.MatlabObject'>
```

Now, i want the contents of key X as a numpy array.

```
Y = np.array(Y['X'])
```

does not work. When i print Y, this is what i get:

```
array([[(array([[[........]]]), array([[  5, 201,  61]], dtype=uint8))]],
  dtype=[('data', 'O'), ('size', 'O')])
```

How do i access the elements of the array?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Did you try `Y['X'][0]`?

Comment: Or you could read the documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/io.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Y['X'][0][0] of the matlab object did the trick! thank you for pointing in the right direction!

Comment: Recently I explored how a `numpy` structured array is handled by `savemat/loadmat`.  At the MATLAB end it is imported as `struct`.  In `scipy` is imported a structured array with object dtype fields.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70963723/saving-a-structured-numpy-array-with-scipy-io-savemat-then-reloading-it-changes/70965097?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#70965097